# This integral... Please help (those that look like seven are zs)

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$
 \int_0^4 z \left(\sqrt{16 - z^2} - \sqrt{25 - z^2} + 3 \right) dz
$$

I'm studying for measure theory but i got stuck on this integral. I tried solving it by parts but i get stuck over the same pattern on functions in the new integral.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Please take a look at how to [format mathematics here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). Also please add some context to the question, as well as your own attempts at solving it

Comment: I see that you are not a new user, but the message still applies

Comment: Yeah, not new but it's the first time i use it

Comment: It's not clear how there can be $d\theta\,dz$ when there is only one range of integration.

Comment: Distribute the $z$ and do each separately.  The first two are a substitution for $a - z^2$.

Comment: Yeah, i messed up, sorry, I'm working on it, leave theta alone, just the dz

Comment: Hint : The function $\large f(x)=\arcsin(x)$ comes into play, which has derivate $\large f'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Comment: Joe Johnson, i did distribute the z, I'm having trouble with each separate small integral that has the squareroot in it. Do you think i should substitute the a-z^2? With what?

Comment: Hint: $(z^2)'=2z$. Split the integral and use the chain rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$2\pi \int_0^4 z \left(\sqrt{16 - z^2} - \sqrt{25 - z^2} + 3 \right) \, dz$$
is same as 
$$2\pi \left( \int_0^4 z \left(\sqrt{16 - z^2} \right) - \int_0^4 z\left(\sqrt{25 - z^2}\right) + \left(\int_0^43 \right) \right)\, dz$$
Use substitutions $z=4cos\theta$ in the first integral and a similar one in the second integral.

Comment: you can simply let $16-z^2 = t$, so that $-2z \, dz = dt$ ? :)

Comment: oh yeah!! Lot better that way

Comment: Got it, I'm terrible with analysis :) Thanks :)